# Find max date from a string array of dates using max function of date-fns

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, date-fns

Dates string array is constructed from backend data object as below:

```
const dates: string[] = this.data.map((item:any) => item.date.jsdate);
```

The result is

```
dates = [
    Thu Jan 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Time), 
    Tue Feb 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Time), 
    Sun Jan 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Time)
]
```

typeof(dates) is "object"

How to find the get the latest date among the jsdates array?

Is it possible to apply max function of date-fns?

Comment: https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert each to a `Date` object and compare using `getTime()` function.

```js
var dates = [
    'Thu Jan 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Time)', 
    'Tue Feb 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Time)', 
    'Sun Jan 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Time)'
]

console.log(
  dates.sort((a,b)=>new Date(b).getTime() - new Date(a).getTime())[0]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can offer one solution, using the momentjs (https://momentjs.com/) library.

You can sort the dates using:

`dates = dates.sort((a,b) => moment(a).diff(moment(b));`

Then if you want the latest date you could take the last element from that array:

`return dates[dates.length-1];`

You should also be able to do this without moment:

`dates = dates.sort((a,b) => new Date(b) - new Date(a));`

Comment: useful but searching for a solution without using momentjs lib. Thanks.

Comment: use the same approach but just converting the date in timestamp and comparing both dates in the sort function

Comment: Just edited the answer to include a potential solution w/o moment